# Correlation heatmap from Excel file

Tags: r, heatmap, correlation

I am trying to represent Jaccard indexes in a correlation map/heatmap.

My input file is an Excel file and it appears that I need to "melt" the data but it won"t work because the first line of my table is set as character and not numeric as the others.

I am trying to do something similar to this but with my excel file as input and I dont need to perform the correlation as I already have the indexes:

```
structure(list(X = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), A = c("1", "0,27", "0,27", "0,25"), B = c("", "1", "0,29", "0,21"), C = c("", "", "1", "0,86"), D = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

mydata <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
dim(mydata)
head(mydata)

cormat <- round(x = cor(mydata), digits = 2)
head(cormat)

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

melted_cormat <- melt(cormat)
head(melted_cormat)

ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: This code appears to work without issue, is it just the excel file that's causing problems?

Comment: Hi @Marie GEBELIN, maybe you could provide us some data from your excel file using `dput(your data)`. So we could help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @r2evans yes it is working with the mtcars data, it appears it is my Excel file thats causing problems.

Comment: @Quinten here is what i get for my csv file using the dput : structure(list(X = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), A = c("1", "0,27", 
"0,27", "0,25"), B = c("", "1", "0,29", "0,21"), C = c("", "", 
"1", "0,86"), D = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)). Hope it helps, i'm a newby in R so sorry if my post in a bit confused

Comment: Marie, a few things: (1) it's generally best to include very-relevant data in the question itself, please [edit] your question and include that `structure(..)` in a code block. (2) Is that data `cormat` or `melted_cormat` or something else? (3) The values are strings that look like they should be numbers in a different locale (comma-decimal), so perhaps something in your process inadvertently converted numbers to strings?